# How to make adjacent polygons align with the edited polygon in leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw, leaflet-geoman, leaflet.pm

Is there any way in Leaflet to edit a shape file (from database) consisting of adjacent polygons in the same manner as in QGIS using the "Reshape feature"-tool in the Advanced Edit toolbar?

At the moment I'm using Leaflet.pm to edit. It works fine to reshape an activated polygon by draging coordinates, but I would like adjacent polygons to align to the new shape. And draging coordinates can turn into a lot of work. Drawing the new boarder as with "reshape feature"-tool would be ideal. Anyone know if it's possible and if so: how?

Thanks!